# Javascript use variable outside a function issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently learning node.js and already meet several times the same problem that seems very simple but I can't still understand how to solve it.

**Code:**

```
var SRC_PORT = 6025;
var dgram = require('dgram');
var clientUDP = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var test

clientUDP.bind(SRC_PORT, function () {
    multicastNew()
});

function multicastNew() {
    var test = 777
    console.log(test);
}
```

**Problem**
Cant use variable test content outside the function `multicastNew()`

In the function `multicastNew()` I have a variable `var test`. In that function `multicastNew()` I gave to `test = 777`. When I want to `console.log(test)` in the same function `multicastNew()` everything works,it outputs `777`. The problem is that when I want to `console.log(test)` outside function `multicastNew()` it outputs `undefined`.

Can you please explain me how to solve this issue and why it is.
Thank you!

Comment: to make your variable global  just remove var

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change `var test = 777;` to `test = 777;` in `mulitcastNew()`. Your code should be as such:

```
var SRC_PORT = 6025;
var dgram = require('dgram');
var clientUDP = dgram.createSocket("udp4");
var test;

clientUDP.bind(SRC_PORT, function () {
    multicastNew();
});

function multicastNew() {
    test = 777;
    console.log(test);
}
```

A note on  scope. In Javascript, functions create scope. Any `variable` defined with `var` inside of a function is a local variable, invisible outside the function. It's only local to the wrapping `function`, and if there is no `wrapping function`, it becomes a global variable.

Consider the following:

```
//this is global scope
var a = "Chris";
var b = "Inspired";

function nameChange(){
    var a = "inspired"; // local to the function nameChange()
    b = "Chris"; //without var we are changing the global variable
    console.log(a); //will output inspired
}
nameChange(); // inspired
console.log(a); // Chris
console.log(b); // Chris
```

Comment: The problem is that in the function multicast I am adding a value to the varialbe test and afterwards I want to use the same variable with its value in another function.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about function scope. When u declare `var test = 777`, then u are creating new variable in scope of your function `multicastNew()`. This variable  covers your 'main' variable from the global scope... So your function works from now on your local variable, not on the one from the global scope. 
 JavaScript always look for variables inside scope it is called. In your example, when u try to call `test` outside the `multicastNew()`, then current scope is `GLOBAL`, so it finds your `var test` from the begining of your code. It's always work from inside to outside [(closures)](http://jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/closures.html). 
 **You can read:** 
[Scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)