# How to define the guild at the top of the code to use in other functions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to add a Global Variable (`server`) that contains my guild's ID, then I could use, for example: `const channel_NAME = server.channels.cache.get('MY CHANNEL ID');` in the top of the code to define all my channels, instead of: `member.guild.roles.cache.get('MY ROLE ID');` in every function.

I did it, but this error is returning to me:

```
const channel_boi_salve = server.channels.cache.get('MY CHANNEL ID');  
TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
```

My code is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
// Guild ID
const server = bot.guilds.cache.get("MY GUILD ID");
// Channels (channel_NAME)
const channel_boi_salve = server.channels.cache.get('MY CHANNEL ID');
```

I'm new to JavaScript so I would appreciate it if someone could explain in detail how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this code in the `client.on("ready"...)` section of your code, because the client has not yet connected to the discord api, so of course, the servers/channels are undefined.

Comment: I tried this, but with this method I can use the server variable only in client.on("ready") function.

Comment: that's what global variables are for. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33659398/javascript-use-variable-outside-a-function-issue

Comment: I tried this too, I put "const server;" in the top of the code, then "server = bot.guilds..." inside "bot.on("ready"...)" and the "channels consts" after the key "bot.on("ready"){ ... }); const channel_Name = server .channels...". And I have the same error, "Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined".